# How to reset/clear aiohttp session

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have been doing some testing with [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and back-connect proxies (the IP changes on each request). The biggest issue with working with back-connect proxies, is sometimes you do not get a good proxy. Regardless though, I still need the request to go through for that specific URL no matter what. I created an example that requests http://ip4.me 10,000 times and retrieves the IP address. Everything works at the start, but eventually, it starts having the error:

> local variable 'ip' referenced before assignment

The reason for this error is because the page I get after requesting is some redirecting page, that takes you to some random site. Here is the HTML (really doesn't matter but I figure I would paint the full picture).

```
<html><head><meta content="2;url=http://ip4.me/?" http-equiv="refresh"/></head><body><iframe frameborder="0" id="f" style="width:1;height:1"></iframe><script>document.getElementById("f").src="http://168.126.130.229/tm/?a=CR&b=WIN&c=300017519516&d=32&e=2205&f=aXA0Lm1l&g=1520816781875&h="+Date.now()+"&y=0&z=0&x=1&w=2017-11-29&in=2205_00002350&id=20180312"</script></body></html>
```

I am guessing I get this page because it is some kind of defense against so many request or something along those lines? Now normally when I get an error with the request (bad proxy, took to long to load, etc..) I just keep trying until I get a good response (which works 90% of the time while this example is running). Like I mentioned earlier, at the very end (when there may be 10 requests left to make). It will keep getting the HTML I posted above and the error I posted above as. This will keep happening over and over.

The only reason I can think that this is happening is that the same session is being used, so the website knows this somehow and just keeps giving me this redirecting page (never allowing it to break out of the While loop). Of course, there could be another reason. If anyone has any insight on why this is happening? Or maybe even a better way to retry the request over (if I get a bad proxy, etc..) it would be much appreciated! Below is my full working example, let me know if you have any questions. Thank you for your time!

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from aiohttp.resolver import AsyncResolver

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, headers, proxy):
        self.headers = headers
        self.proxy = proxy

    async def build(self, dataset):
        tasks = []
        resolver = AsyncResolver(nameservers=["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"])
        connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1500, limit_per_host=0, resolver=resolver, use_dns_cache=False)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
            for data in range(0,dataset):
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.fetch(session, data))
                tasks.append(task)
            r = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            return r

    async def fetch(self, session, data):
        while True:
            try:
                async with session.get('http://ip4.me', headers=self.headers, proxy=self.proxy, timeout=60, ssl=False, allow_redirects=False) as resp:
                    assert resp.status == 200
                    r = await resp.read()
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
                    for font in soup.find_all('font'):
                        ip = font.text
                    print (data, ip)
                    return ip
            except Exception as e:
                print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'}
    proxy = 'XXX.XX.X.XXX:XXXXX'
    proxy = "http://{}".format(proxy)
    dataset = 10000

    px = Proxy(headers, proxy)

    startTime = datetime.now()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(px.build(dataset))
    ip = loop.run_until_complete(future)
    loop.close()
    print (datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Comment: You are assigning `ip` in the body of a for loop. If there are no font tags, it will never receive a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crawling is a big topic.

In your expression, I image that you are using different proxy each request. But in your code, I think you are using the same proxy and the same headers for every requests.

So in this case, it is very easy for server to identify you no matter how you change your session in python code. Because your IP has never changed. That's enough. When server thinks you should be forbidden, it forbids your IP, and then you will be blocked totally, not matter how you try.

Some website provide professional service to solve crawling forbidding. They use different proxies for every different requests in a period of time. And they use randomly generated user agent to dress up as different browser. They also use their huge database to decide pertinent strategy.

So that is not easy. If you are trying to fetch a little data, you can just slow down.

### To use a new session

```
....
resolver = AsyncResolver(nameservers=["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"])
connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1500, limit_per_host=0, resolver=resolver, use_dns_cache=False, force_close=True)
sessions = []
for data in range(0,dataset):
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector)
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.fetch(session, data))
    tasks.append(task)
    sessions.append(session)
r = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
[session.close() for session in sessions]
return r
....
```

`force_close=True` might be useless as you are using different session for each request.

Comment: What? I clearly said that I am using back connect proxies and "the IP changes on each request"? So no, I am not using the same IP for each request. I am using a back connect proxy, which gives me a new IP per request and I am allowed to make up to 1500 request at a time. Please read my question all the way, before answering. Thank you.

Comment: I just didn't realize that the `proxy` in your code is actually a IP pool. So that makes you emotional like this? Why can't you see another possible reason in the second paragraph from bottom of my answer? A user-agent identify a browser , so if you send requests with the same user-agent, server can still identify you. Everyone in this website is trying to help others. You don't need to be emotional like this.

Comment: Emotional? I just said to read my question... but anyways the user-agent is not going to make a difference like that. How many computers out there use that same user-agent? Regardless I already tried rotating user-agents and it did nothing. Anyways... do you have any insight on how to reset/clear the session? I think that is the main issue.

Comment: You just need to create new session for each request. Answer edited.

Comment: Actually, force_close=True is what made it work. I didn't have to do anything else but add that. Thank you very much.